# RegisterClientScriptBlock writing to document instead of registering a script?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "SetInLocalStorage", $"localStorage.setItem('secTok','{token}');");
```

For whatever reason, it's just printing the command onto the rendered html as plain text instead of a javascript block to run.

What do?

Comment: Are you using `Page.ClientScript` and getting script errors in browser console? Where the script content rendered?

Comment: No errors. It literally prints text on the page as though it's just doing something like a document.write.